# Why can not make a declaration directly in a page class in case of session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

My question is one line yet this is very confusing me.
Why i can not declare and initialize a session variable in partial class of a page it throws an error saying

> Error 1   Invalid token '[' in class,
>   struct, or interface member
>   declaration   E:\ASP.NET\Trial\statemanagement.aspx.cs    17  12  E:\ASP.NET\Trial\

below is the code i tried

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class statemanagement : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int count=0;
    Session["FirstName"] = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
         count = int.Parse(Session["FirstName"].ToString());
     }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Write(count.ToString());
        Session["FirstName"] =++count;

    }
}
```

i dont get the error for count variable i dont know why?

Any help will be regarded thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a declaration. It is an assignment. You can not place an assignment statement directly inside a class. You have to place it inside a method or property.

Refering to [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

> Session variables are stored in a
>   [SessionStateItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstateitemcollection.aspx) object that
>   is exposed through the
>   [HttpContext.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) property. In an
>   ASP.NET page, the current session
>   variables are exposed through the
>   Session property of the Page object.
>
> The collection of session variables is
>   indexed by the name of the variable or
>   by an integer index. Session variables
>   are created by referring to the
>   session variable by name. You do not
>   have to declare a session variable or
>   explicitly add it to the collection.

If you like to initialize the session variables independently from the page you can use application event handlers such as `Application_Start` and `Session_Start` which you can find in the *global.asax* file .

Comment: let me clear assignment is possible in partial class as i know i can assign the value in int count it throw no exception at all :)

Comment: @Devjosh: Let me correct you dear, you can assign a value to a variable directly inside a class only when you are declaring it .. Again, `Session["Key"] = value;` is not a declaration, but only an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `Session["FirstName"] = 0;` outside the scope of a method.  Try moving it down to be inside `Page_Load`.

Comment: i know and done it that way but i just want to dig the reason why it's not allowed anyways and also i can assign the count var which is int type its running fine? thanks